# how to mutate a column with ID in group

Tags: r, dplyr

how to mutate a column with ID in group

data.frame like:

```
a b c
1 a 1 1
2 a 1 2
3 a 2 3
4 b 1 4
5 b 2 5
6 b 3 6
```

group by a, flag start with 1, if b equals pre b,then flag=1 else flag+=1

```
  a b c flag
1 a 1 1    1  <-  group a start with 1
2 a 1 2    1  <-- in group a, 1(in row 2)=1(in row 1)
3 a 2 3    2  <-  in group a, 2(in row 3)!=1(in row 2)
4 b 1 4    1  <-  group b start with 1
5 b 2 5    2  <-  in group b, 2(in row 5)!=1(in row 4)
6 b 3 6    3  <-  in group b, 3(in row 6)!=2(in row 5)
```

Comment: it's a bit telegram (or twitter) style annd there's an error in the example, but other than that this is a well defined question. The only thing I miss, is a "I tried this, but it didn't work".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to do. But it seems to me that you are trying to assign index numbers to values in b for each group (a or b).

```
#I modified your example here.

a <- rep(c("a","b"), each =3)
b <- c(4,4,5,11,12,13)
c <- 1:6

foo <- data.frame(a,b,c, stringsAsFactors = F)

  a  b c
1 a  4 1
2 a  4 2
3 a  5 3
4 b 11 4
5 b 12 5
6 b 13 6

#Since you referred to dplyr, I will use it.

cats <- list()
for(i in unique(foo$a)){

ana <- foo %>%
       filter(a == i) %>%
       arrange(b) %>%
       mutate(indexInb = as.integer(as.factor(b)))

cats[[i]] <- ana

}

bob <- rbindlist(cats)

   a  b c indexInb
1: a  4 1        1
2: a  4 2        1
3: a  5 3        2
4: b 11 4        1
5: b 12 5        2
6: b 13 6        3
```

Answer (score 2):

i now using this:

```
for(i in 2:nrow(x)){
    x[i, 'flag'] = ifelse(x[i, 'a']!=x[i-1,'a'], 1, ifelse(x[i, 'b']==x[i-1, 'b'], x[i-1, 'flag'], x[i-1,'flag']+1))
}
```

but it is inefficiency in large dataset

#

## UPDATE

`dense_rank` in dplyr give me the answer

```
> x %>% group_by(a) %>% mutate(dense_rank(b))
Source: local data frame [10 x 4]
Groups: a

   a b  c dense_rank(b)
1  a x  1             1
2  a x  2             1
3  a y  3             2
4  b x  4             1
5  b y  5             2
6  b z  6             3
7  c x  7             1
8  c y  8             2
9  c z  9             3
10 c z 10             3
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hers's a quick vectorized way to solve this without using any `for` loops

Base R solution using `ave` and `transform`

```
transform(x, flag = ave(b, a, FUN = function(x) cumsum(c(1, diff(x)))))
#   a b c flag
# 1 a 1 1    1
# 2 a 1 2    1
# 3 a 2 3    2
# 4 b 1 4    1
# 5 b 2 5    2
# 6 b 3 6    3
```

Or a `data.table` solution (more efficient)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x)[, flag := cumsum(c(1, diff(b))), by = a]
x
#    a b c flag
# 1: a 1 1    1
# 2: a 1 2    1
# 3: a 2 3    2
# 4: b 1 4    1
# 5: b 2 5    2
# 6: b 3 6    3
```

Or a `dplyr` solution (because you tagged it)

```
library(dplyr)
x %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  mutate(flag = cumsum(c(1, diff(b))))
# Source: local data frame [6 x 4]
# Groups: a
# 
#   a b c flag
# 1 a 1 1    1
# 2 a 1 2    1
# 3 a 2 3    2
# 4 b 1 4    1
# 5 b 2 5    2
# 6 b 3 6    3
```

Comment: sorry, i didnt make my question clearly. column b can be character like c('a','a','b','a','b','c'). but still thanks. i use `x %>% mutate(dense_rank(b))` to solve it.

Comment: quickest route to sticking that in your data frame is then `x$flag = dense_rank(x$b)` and you don't need any pipes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I could not find how to come up with the index numbers with `mutate()`. I learned from your answer. Thank you.