# dplyr append group id sequence?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset like below, it's created by dplyr and currently grouped by ‘Stage', how do I generate a sequence based on unique, incremental value of Stage, starting from 1 (for eg row$4 should be 1 row#1 and #8 should be 4)

```
     X   Y Stage Count
1   61  74     1     2
2   58  56     2     1
3   78  76     0     1
4  100 100    -2     1
5   89  88    -1     1
6   47  44     3     1
7   36  32     4     1
8   75  58     1     2
9   24  21     5     1
10  12  11     6     1
11   0   0    10     1
```

I tried the approach in below post but didn't work.
[how to mutate a column with ID in group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25658916/how-to-mutate-a-column-with-id-in-group)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another dplyr solution:

```
> df
# A tibble: 11 × 4
       X     Y Stage Count
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     61    74     1     2
2     58    56     2     1
3     78    76     0     1
4    100   100    -2     1
5     89    88    -1     1
6     47    44     3     1
7     36    32     4     1
8     75    58     1     2
9     24    21     5     1
10    12    11     6     1
11     0     0    10     1
```

To create the group id's use dpylr's group_indicies:

```
i <- df %>% group_indices(Stage)
df %>% mutate(group = i)

# A tibble: 11 × 5
       X     Y Stage Count group
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1     61    74     1     2     4
2     58    56     2     1     5
3     78    76     0     1     3
4    100   100    -2     1     1
5     89    88    -1     1     2
6     47    44     3     1     6
7     36    32     4     1     7
8     75    58     1     2     4
9     24    21     5     1     8
10    12    11     6     1     9
11     0     0    10     1    10
```

It would be great if you could pipe both commands together. [But, as of this writing, it doesn't appear to be possible](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1185).

Comment: In one line : `df %>% group_indices(Stage) %>% mutate(.data = df) %>% rename(group=".")`

Answer (score 1):

After some experiment, I did `%>% ungroup() %>% mutate(test = rank(Stage))`, which will yield the following result.

```
     X   Y Stage Count test
1  100 100    -2     1  1.0
2   89  88    -1     1  2.0
3   78  76     0     1  3.0
4   61  74     1     2  4.5
5   75  58     1     2  4.5
6   58  56     2     1  6.0
7   47  44     3     1  7.0
8   36  32     4     1  8.0
9   24  21     5     1  9.0
10  12  11     6     1 10.0
11   0   0    10     1 11.0
```

I don't know whether this is the best approach, feel free to comment....

## update

Another approach, assuming the data called Node

```
lvs <- levels(as.factor(Node$Stage))
Node %>% mutate(Rank = match(Stage,lvs))
```

Comment: Better to use `row_number()`